# Flexible Safe Array C++

Tags: c++, arrays, class

My safearray can hold any type of data and can be resized if needed. What I have got it set to do is if the user inputs an array size that is smaller that the index in the for loop(30 in this case), it will resize itself. However it makes it too big so I just have a lot of zeros. for example if I input size 15, it will make it size 45 which allows me to store all the data but I have extra spaces I do not need. My TA says this is fine for a good grade, but since It's not due for another couple of days I would like to have a resize function that resizes the array to be exactly the same size as the index regardless of what the user input size is. I'm not sure how best to do this. Any help? thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


template<typename Element>
class SafeArray
{
   int size;
    Element*Array;
    Element def;

public:
    SafeArray()                         //default constructor(with no parameter)
    {
        Array = new Element[size];
    size = 10;
    }
    SafeArray(int value = NULL)         //constructor with one int
    {
        Array = new Element[value];
        size = value;
    }
    ~SafeArray() { delete [] Array;};                     //destructor

      Element get(int pos)                    //get method
    { if (pos<0)
    {cout<<"error";}

        if(pos>=size)
        { set_default(def);}
        return Array[pos]; }

    void set(int pos, Element val)      //set method
    { if (pos<0)
    {
        cout<<"error";
    }
        if(pos>=size)
    { resize(3); }
        Array[pos] = val; }

    void resize(int size_mult)           //resize function
    {
            Element*temp=new Element[size*size_mult];
            for(int i = 0; i<size;i++)
            {temp[i]=Array[i];}
            delete[]Array;
            Array = temp;
            size=size*size_mult;
        }
    void set_default(Element d)        //set_default(just a safety precaution, doesn't really effect the outcome)
    {
         def=d;
    }
    //Element get_default()
   // {
   //     return def;
   // }
    int get_size()                       //get size
    {
        return size;
    }
};


int main()
{

    int N;
    cout<<"How big should the Array be?"<<endl;
    cin>>N;
    SafeArray<int> X(N);
    SafeArray<double>Y(N);
    X.set_default(-1);
    cout<<"Array is size "<<X.get_size()<<endl;

    for(int i=0; i<30;i++)

    {
        int x=i*3+1;
        double y =1000.0/x;
        X.set(i,x);
        Y.set(i,y);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= X.get_size(); i += 1)
        {if(i<10)
            cout <<"0"<< i << ": x = " << X.get(i) << ", 1000/x = " << Y.get(i) << "\n";
        else
        cout << i << ": x = " << X.get(i) << ", 1000/x = " << Y.get(i) << "\n";}
            cout<<"Array is size "<<X.get_size()<<endl;

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: I guess just handing in a wrapper of `std::vector` would be cheating? Would be the technically best solution for sure.  :)

Comment: `if(pos>=size) { resize(3); }` is not safe: what if I create `SafeArray<int> X(10)` and then write `X.set(100, 1)` ?

Comment: Yeah we're not allowed to user std::vector in this class. Would be nice.

Comment: @Inspired yeah that seems to work but as part of the criteria for the assignment I have to have a resize method in my SafeArray class that does it. Plus it only works if the index is 30. If I change it to 40, then it just sets the array size to 90

Comment: Creating a variable by `type name(value);` is not a good idea, cause you are not actually creating a variable, its even possible that the compiler do not allow you to do this (or warns you when you do). This is called 'Most vexing parse'.  C++11 introduced the possibility to initialize variables with the {} instead of (), do this, or look up info about how to get around the issue.

Comment: In your "default" constructor, `Array = new Element[size];` um.. and when did `size` receive its value? The *next* line? Fyi this code is *begging* for construction intializers.

Answer (score 0):

Well there are some things to consider.

1. Are you looking to save on space or on time complexity? The way you have it set up now (multiplying current length by some multiple) saves drastically on your time complexity, but as you pointed out uses some extra space. Usually programmers look to minimize time complexity, but it all depends on your goals.

Note: I may be wise to just multiply by 2 vs a passed in multiple because you will gain the same time benefits, but not produce so much space on larger resizes. (i.e. 10,000 * 2 = 20,000 vs 10,000 * 3 = 30,000 saves 10,000 spaces you may not end up needing)

2. While not directly related to your question and maybe out of the scope of your lab problem, the way you are building this is similar to a map/hash table in that any index you choose will store some value, but say you have this scenario. SafeArray.length is 10 and you place an item at index 1000. You will end not resizing your array enough the your currently implement SafeArray and get an out of bounds error. Even if you do resize it enough there will be postions from 10 - 999 all empty which is a huge waste and you will have to remember that you have some value at 1000 with nothing in between. Some additional rules/restrictions on how SafeArray should work may be wise if you plan on using this as a real data structure.

Now to truely answer your question, the best way is to make a for loop from 0 to the index and just copy values into the new array and make the very last statement be the new value assignement. See below

Set would become:

```
void set(int pos, Element val)      //set method
{ if (pos<0)
{
    cout<<"error";
}
    if(pos>=size)
{ resize(pos+1); }
    Array[pos] = val; }
```

Resize would look like this:

```
void resize(int new_size)           //resize function
{
        Element*temp=new Element[new_size];
        for(int i = 0; i<new_size;i++)
        {temp[i]=Array[i];}
        delete[]Array;
        Array = temp;
        size=new_size;
    }
```

Edit:
If you don't care about the space as much, want some time savings, and still have a safe in bounds assignment (which someone pointed out in the comments on your question) you could use the following for the Set method:

Set:

```
void set(int pos, Element val)      //set method
{ if (pos<0)
{
    cout<<"error";
}
    if(pos>=size)
{ resize((pos - size) * 2); }
    Array[pos] = val; }
```

This will give you some extra space and you can use a larger multiple than 2 to gain better time savings in the sequential case (i.e. adding by for loop).

Comment: Note that the answer I gave to minimize the space you need to make your SafeArray work properly has really bad time complexity when you step sequentially in a for loop and add values as each next step forces you to perform the O(n) resize.

Comment: This works pretty good but if the user types in a number larger than the index then it will print the array larger than the index. i.e 20 will change to 30 which is good. but 40 will stay at 40, I also need it to resize down if the input is too big for the index

Comment: To answer your question I am looking to save space. I just need a resize that will resize to the index size whether the input is too high or too low.  Also thanks for other hints. I'll keep them in mind

Comment: Actually it will work how you want I think. Say size is 40 and I enter a value at index 40, the Set method will resize (i.e. if(pos>=size)
{ resize(pos+1); }) pos+1 = 41 which makes it work and 40 >= 40.

Comment: If you resize down, you could lose items you have stored at larger values correct? I think what you have is fine for your homework, but for a real data structure, this really needs to be defined a little differently. Good luck in you class though! These kind of classes really get you thinking about the important stuff in programming :)

Comment: I just tried it. if this index is 30 and i input 40 for size of array it will print data up till size 30 then just print zeroes and stuff till index 40. It works if the user types something less than 30, but not if they type something more than 30. I would like it to only print out 30 things regardless of what the user types

Comment: Right, but adding an item at position 40 should be an error then because 40 is > than your array size correct? There is no way to place an item at position 40 without having null/0 values in between your old values and the position you are placing at. That's why I mentioned the map/hash table. This structure does exactly what you want, but does not show the empty spaces, but I don't know if that what your homework assignment calls for. It's a completely different type of data structure than what you currently have laid out.

Comment: Even with the hash table, the spaces still exist, they just aren't shown when display is called. There is no way around that as far as I know for array style access. If there is please let me know because I love learning new things!